# Subclass of class with synthesized readonly property cannot access instance variable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, inheritance, subclass

In the superclass `MyClass`:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *pString;

@end

@implementation MyClass

@synthesize pString = _pString;

@end
```

In the subclass `MySubclass`

```
@interface MySubclass : MyClass

@end

@implementation MySubclass

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _pString = @"Some string";
    }
    return self;
}
```

The problem is that the compiler doesn't think that `_pString` is a member of `MySubclass`, but I have no problem accessing it in `MyClass`.

What am I missing?

Comment: try [super setPString:] or [self setPString:]

Comment: tried to remove readonly property like below @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *pString;

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The instance variable `_pString` produced by `@synthesize` is *private* to `MyClass`. You need to make it *protected* in order for `MySubclass` to be able to access it.

Add an ivar declaration for `_pString` in the `@protected` section of `MyClass`, like this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    @protected
    NSString *_pString;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *pString;

@end
```

Now synthesize the accessors as usual, and your variable will become accessible to your subclass.

Comment: Yes, you will...if it is from a subclass that has access to the underlying variable.

Comment: @Owl You will not be able to set the string through the property, but you will be able to set the string to the backing variable, which will have the effect of `pString` property changing its value. You need to set `_pString = @"abc"`, not `self.pString = @"abc"`.

Comment: @Owl what dasblinken said!  You don't HAVE to set the variable through its property interface.  This way objects that don't inherit from the class cannot change the variable.  It is readonly except to children.

Comment: Just a semantic question about stack...does "oldest" answer go by creation time or edit time?

Comment: Good answer. I would personally use a double under score to indicate that you are accessing a protected ivar on a superclass and explicitly @synthesize it:

Comment: A small reminder: in the subclass use the ivar (_myVariable) instead of the accessor (self.myVariable).

Answer (score 5):

I am familiar with this problem.  You synthesize the variable in your .m class, so it is not imported along with the header since the _pString variable will be created as part of the implementation, and not the interface.  The solution is to declare _pString in your header interface and then synthesize it anyway (it will use the existing variable instead of creating a private one).

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSString *_pString; //Don't worry, it will not be public
}

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *pString;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The given answer works perfectly fine. This is an alternative answer, that apparently Apple [likes a bit more](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW6).

You can define a [private extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW6) of your class, a `MyClass+Protected.h` file, which needs to be included in `MyClass.m` and `MySubclass.m`.

Then, in this new file, you redefine the property as `readwrite`.

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (strong, readwrite) NSString * pString;
@end
```

This alternative allows you to use the accessor `self.pString` rather than the ivar `_pString`.

Note: you still need to keep the definition of `pString` in your `MyClass.h` as is.