# override property from superclass in subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to override an NSString property declared in a superclass. When I try to do it using the default ivar, which uses the the same name as the property but with an underscore, it's not recognised as a variable name. It looks something like this...

The interface of the superclass(I don't implement the getter or setter in this class):

```
//Animal.h
@interface Animal : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *species;

@end
```

The implementation in the subclass:

```
//Human.m
@implementation

- (NSString *)species
{
    //This is what I want to work but it doesn't and I don't know why 
    if(!_species) _species = @"Homo sapiens";

    return _species;

}

@end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What XCode version are you using?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Closely related (the same problem, in fact): [Subclass of class with synthesized readonly property cannot access instance vari](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10943042)

Comment: @H2CO3 _species isn't recognised as a variable name when I do it like this... I should have mad it clearer:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only the superclass has access to the ivar `_species`. Your subclass should look like this:

```
- (NSString *)species {
    NSString *value = [super species];
    if (!value) {
        self.species = @"Homo sapiens";
    }

    return [super species];
}
```

That sets the value to a default if it isn't currently set at all. Another option would be:

```
- (NSString *)species {
    NSString *result = [super species];
    if (!result) {
        result = @"Home sapiens";
    }

    return result;
}
```

This doesn't update the value if there is no value. It simply returns a default as needed.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what's going on:). Why doesn't returning [super species] in the first one just return the nil?

Comment: In the first block of code, ‘super species‘ is called twice. Which one do you want to know about?

Comment: The second [super species].

Comment: It doesn't return nil because of the call to `self.species = @"Homo sapient";`

Comment: This solution requires the property to be readwrite, so anyone could change the species of the subclass instance at any time.  Not great.

Answer (score 1):

to access the superclass variables, they must be marked as @protected, access to such variables will be only inside the class and its heirs

```
@interface ObjectA : NSObject
{
    @protected NSObject *_myProperty;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSObject *myProperty;
@end

@interface ObjectB : ObjectA
@end

@implementation ObjectA
@synthesize myProperty = _myProperty;
@end

@implementation ObjectB
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        _myProperty = [NSObject new];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: instead of doing gray boxing, you should call the super classes properties/methods through the public interface, as shown by rmaddy.