# objective-c rename/override parent property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

Is there an easy way to rename a parent's property or have a new property reuse an existing one?

For example, I have a parent class defined as such:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
    @property NSString* Name;
@end
```

If I want a child class to use that Name property but to call it something else, I know I can do something like this:

```
@interface Child : Parent
    @property NSString* ChildName;
@end

@implementation Child

- (void) setChildName:(NSString *)ChildName
{
    [super setName:ChildName];
}

- (NSString *) ChildName
{
    return [super Name];
}

@end
```

But is there an easier way of doing this with getter/setter? This didn't work for me:

```
@interface Child : Parent
    @property (getter=Name, setter=setName) NSString* ChildName;
@end
```

Comment: Please read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html and name your methods and variables properly.

Comment: I have and I've never seen a section detailing something like this. Did I miss it?

Comment: I suggest reading that as an aside. Your original problem may or may not be related to that, but it sure as hell makes it easier for others to help you sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

Oren is correct, you've got some work to do with understanding properties, but you could try setting the getter/setter like this:

```
@interface Child : Parent
    @property (getter=childName, setter=setChildName) NSString* Name;
@end
```

You will likely want to add (strong, nonatomic) in your property description as well (or whatever would be appropriate for your context).

Comment: But this doesn't actually override the parent's implementation, right? Meaning if I have an instance of Child, it'll work if I call myChild.Name, since that property is using ChildName. However if I cast that Child to its Parent, then myParent.Name would return nil since that property was never actually set.

Comment: But you can synthesize it in the subclass.

Comment: Perhaps this related post will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127056/override-property-from-superclass-in-subclass

Comment: That's essentially what I did above, where the child just calls super's version. I was just hoping there'd be an easier way so I don't have to recreate all the properties again in the child. Specifying the getter/setter seemed logical to me but not sure why it wouldn't work